# Tutte's matrix for perfect matching in bipartite graphs

Tags: determinant, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I came across Tutte's matrix for a bipartite graph $G(U, V, E)$ in two different forms.
One form (seen in these notes for example https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f04/www/scribes/lec3.pdf) says the matrix M is defined by $$M_{ij} = \begin{cases} x_{ij} \; \text{if}\;  (u_i, v_j) \in E \\ 0 \; \text{if}\;\; (u_i, v_j) \notin E \end{cases}$$

However, other statements and answers on this site state that matrix $M$ is skew-symmetric.

The proof in the notes that shows perfect matching occurs iff $\det(M)$ is non-singular seems to be much easier with the first definition (that does not involve skew-symmetry). Are these two forms equivalent, or is there a reason the first is incorrect ?

Answer (score 1):

The formula in these lecture notes is actually a formula for the [Edmonds matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds_matrix). It is only defined for bipartite graphs (since the bipartition is baked into the definition) and it only make sense to take its determinant when the bipartite graph is balanced.

The skew-symmetric [Tutte matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_matrix) is a generalization for *any* graph. For completeness, here is the definition: it is a matrix $A$ where $$A_{ij} = \begin{cases}x_{ij} & ij \in E, i<j \\ -x_{ij} & ij \in E, i>j \\ 0 & ij \notin E\end{cases}$$
This does not require a graph to be bipartite, and even if the graph is bipartite, it does not require us to know the bipartition.

However, suppose that the graph *is* a balanced bipartite graph, and further suppose that we sort the vertices in the order $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$. Then if we use this order to index the rows and columns of the Tutte matrix $A$, it will have the block form $$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & M \\ -M^{\mathsf T} & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ where $M$ is the Edmonds matrix. We will have $\det(A) = \det(M)^2$, so if one determinant is nonzero, so is the other. This makes sense, since for bipartite graphs, both should tell us if a perfect matching exists.

The Tutte matrix can also tell us if a perfect matching exists in a non-bipartite graph, however.